# Mysql syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

** The Code**

```
$ah_title = $_POST['ah_title'];
$ah_postin = $_POST['ah_postin'];
$ah_content = $_POST['ah_content'];
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');   
$ah_date = date("m/d/y");
$ah_query = "INSERT INTO '$ah_title' (title,content,date) VALUES ('$ah_title','$ah_content','$ah_date') ";
```

** The Error **

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''test' (title,content,date) VALUES ('test','test','02/09/12')' at line 1
```

Can you please help me understand the error and how to fix it.

Comment: Thank you eveyrone for your fast response I figured it out I needed the table to be $ah_postin not $sh_title thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inserting into the table 'test'.  Do you have a table named test?  INSERT INTO $ah_title?  Are you sure thats accurate?

Comment: Thank you very much this was my problem

Answer (score 1):

Don't wrap the table name in quotes

```
$ah_query = "INSERT INTO $ah_title (title,content,date) VALUES ('$ah_title','$ah_content','$ah_date') ";
```

And please secure against SQL injection

```
$ah_title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ah_title'];
```

It's not apparent what you're using as a database library so the exact method of escaping is unknown.

Comment: @Cjueden Going to have to give us more than that. My car won't work - can you fix it for me over the phone without asking me for any additional details?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use single quote to escape entity name. Use back-quote.

```
$ah_query = "INSERT INTO `$ah_title` (`title`,`content`,`date`) VALUES ('$ah_title','$ah_content','$ah_date') ";
```

Answer (score 0):

`DATE` is a reserved word in MySQL. You need to use backticks around it, as well as using backticks around the table name instead of single quotes